# Change condition from column index to column value in DB cross tab in Fast Report

Tags: crosstab, fastreport

I have a scrip in DB Cross tab in fast report but i want change condition from ColumnIndex to ColumnValue

```
procedure DBCross1OnPrintCell(Memo: TfrxMemoView; RowIndex, ColumnIndex, CellIndex: Integer; RowValues, ColumnValues, Value: Variant);
begin 
if ColumnIndex = 0 then
if Value <> null then
 Set('Var0', Value)
else
Set('Var0', 0);
 if DBCross1.IsGrandTotalColumn(ColumnIndex) then
Memo.Text := Format('%2.0n', [StrToFloat(VarToStr(value- Get('Var0')))]);
end;
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M5RH6.png)

I want Instead ColumnIndex = 0 . i have for example
if ColumnValue = 'joy' and columnvalue = 'jack'
...

Comment: What does `if ColumnValue = 'joy' and columnvalue = 'jack'`  mean? Column value can have one value only

Comment: I Have 2 column Header . columnHeader[1] = Code1 and ColumnHeader[2]= Code2
and Code1 Values = Joy or X ....     
and Code2 Values = Jack or Y ...... ok ? or Did i Explain more ?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
procedure Cross1OnPrintCell(Memo: TfrxMemoView; RowIndex, ColumnIndex, CellIndex: Integer; RowValues, ColumnValues, Value: Variant);
begin
  if ColumnValues[0] = '2000' then if ColumnValues[1] = '2' then Memo.Color := clRed;                                                                                                               
end;
```

Comment: Hi gear Gpi . 
I change columIndex to ColumnValues But I get an error : could not convert variant of type (َArray variant) into type (Integer) ????

Comment: Create a small demo project with error and send it to support@fast-report.com